# Read from a file and return new line with loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file like

foo.txt

```
xxx B=C     D: A
yyy F=H     D:A
zzz K=L     D:  A
fff M=H     D:/llll
kkk S=D     D: /kkkkk
```

this is what I try to get;

```
xxx B=C;     D: A           ;pass
yyy F=H;     D:A            ;pass
zzz K=L;     D:  A          ;pass
fff M=H;     D:/llll        ;try
kkk S=D;     D: /kkkkk/bb   ;try
```

The second part of line which starts with "D:",if starts with "/", it should be write "try" else it has to write "pass" end of the line for every line in it.

I can read file like this but there is spaces which is another problem

In addition after "D:" always starts with "A" or "/".

I tried while loop but I have not succeeded.

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | cut -d ":" -f,2
```

Output

```
 A      (one empty space)
A       (none)
   A    (three empty space)
/llll   (none)
 /kkkkk/bb (two empty space)
```

This is a example what I have tried

```
while read -r line;
do 
if [[ $line ]]; then
          echo $line "try"
else
          echo $line "pass" 
fi
done < foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write in the same file, I would recommend to create a new file and then rename it.

```
tmpFile="/tmp/foo2.txt.tmp"

cat /tmp/foo.txt | while read line; do
      isSlash=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | grep -c ^"/")
      if (( $isSlash )); then
          echo "$line ;try" >> $tmpFile
      else 
          echo "$line ;pass" >> $tmpFile
      fi
done

mv $tmpFile /tmp/foo.txt
```

Comment: kkk S=D     D: /kkkkk ;pass it writes pass beacause of the empty space before the "/" so can we add something that ignore  the empty spaces?

Comment: I updated my answer, `awk '{print $1}'` will solve the issue with the empty space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk), which makes it very easy to accomplish what you want:

```
awk '!/D: *\//{print $0 " ;pass"; next} {print $0 " ;try"}' foo.txt
```

Output:

```
xxx B=C     D: A ;pass
yyy F=H     D:A ;pass
zzz K=L     D:  A ;pass
fff M=H     D:/llll ;try
kkk S=D     D: /kkkkk ;try
```

This basically matches every line *not containing* `D:` and `/` and appends `;pass` to it, then skips to the next line. Otherwise it appends `;try` to it.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` OK?

```
$ sed '/D: *A/ s/$/\t;pass/; /D: *\// s/$/\t;try/' file
 xxx B=C     D: A   ;pass
 yyy F=H     D:A    ;pass
 zzz K=L     D:  A  ;pass
 fff M=H     D:/llll    ;try
 kkk S=D     D: /kkkkk  ;try
```

Comment: posixly: `sed -e 's+D: */.*+&\t;try+ ; t' -e 's+$+\t;pass+'`